# Override Shopware 6 Administration Typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, shopware, shopware6, administration

There is a Shopware Documentation on overwriting components in the administration: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/customizing-components.html

Is such documentation also available for the typescript files (within the administration), which were not registered via "Shopware.Component.register", but run via an "export default"?

**Current specific problem:**

When manually creating an order via the administration area, there are customers who have more than 25 addresses in the customer account. Now you want to select, for example, the 30th address of the customer account when creating an order. However, the selection field for addresses has a fixed limit of 25 in the code, which would not be a problem with pagination, but in this case it means that only the first 25 addresses created are available in the selection field and there is no option to select newer addresses. There is no possibility to change this setting in the administration area.

**My problem with this:**

The file I have to change for this is the following: vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-order/component/sw-order-customer-address-select/index.ts

In these "index.ts" files, "export default" is used instead of "Shopware.Component.register", which means that I cannot customize this file via the normal process according to the documentation. However, I need to change the fixed value in it from 25.

Is there an alternative documentation on how to customize such problems/topics or does anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: Everything that applies to javascript, also applies to typescript